# Snap installation won't start

Tags: 18.04, snap, ubuntu-mate

Installed PHPStorm via snap.

```
sudo snap install phpstorm --classic
```

1) When I try to run it from launcher, it just closes after a few seconds.

2) When I try to run it from terminal, I get: "/ has 'other' write 40777."

My system is Ubuntu Mate 18.04.1 and below info about snap

```
snap --version
snap 2.37
snapd 2.37
series 16
ubuntu 18.04
kernel 4.15.0-45-generic
```

I've tried following suggestion but it didn't worked

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51027327/ubuntu-18-04-var-lib-snapd-has-other-write-40777

Any ideas how to solve this issue? The same installation went without an issue on my main desktop with Ubuntu 18.04.1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I did massive mistake. I've started to investigate and I found out that for some reason my root directory / had 777 permissions! Thankfully I quickly fixed it by doing

```
sudo chmod 755 /
```

After that fix PHPStorm launched without an issue.